# Typescript node promisify "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1"

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use util.promisify with Typescript and "strict": true in compiler options.

```
node 9.7.1
typescript 2.7.2
```

I'm using library firebird-node and I'm trying to use promisify with function "attach".

from the library, the function is declared this way:

```
type DatabaseCallback = (err: any, db: Database) => void;

export function attach(options: Options, callback: DatabaseCallback): void;
```

if I try to use util.promisify

```
const connectionParams: libfirebird.Options = {....};

const p = util.promisify(libfirebird.attach);
this.dbHandle = await p(connectionParams);
```

I get error "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1." in "p(connectionParams)"

I also tried to use it this way

```
this.dbHandle = await util.promisify(libfirebird.attach)(connectionParams);
```

but I got same error.

The solution that I found is to manually construct the promise:

```
this.dbHandle = await new Promise<libfirebird.Database>((resolve, reject) => {
    libfirebird.attach(connectionParams, function(err, db){
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(db);
    });
});
```

Is there any know bug with util.promisify in typescript or I missing something?

Comment: It looks like you need to pass a second parameter to p(...) Where the first parameter is the options (which you already pass in) and the second is the database callback it is going to use?

Comment: Seems that there is/are issues with util.promisify in typescript. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26048, https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20497